# Best practice for deploying migrations on Production Server? (DOTNET Core / 5)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, migration

I use .NET 5 (Core) for my app.
I would like to know what is the best practice to allow server doing migrations script on Production ?
Should I create migrations script --idempotent and run dotnet ef database update on the server ? Or should I give the client pieces of migration scripts and do the update on there ?
Should I put automating the migrationscript on the compiled app ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply EF Core migrations if you should not use MigrateAsync() for production environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761614/how-to-apply-ef-core-migrations-if-you-should-not-use-migrateasync-for-product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Microsoft documentation about migrations in production.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime

You can call the `Database.Migrate();` inside the constructor of your Db Context class or in the dependency inversion process create a scope of the Db Context class and call:

```cs
var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
db.Database.Migrate();
```

But, be aware of the warning:

- Carefully consider before using this approach in production. Experience has shown that the simplicity of this deployment strategy is outweighed by the issues it creates.
- Consider generating SQL scripts from migrations instead.
  Don't call EnsureCreated() before Migrate(). EnsureCreated() bypasses Migrations to create the schema, which causes Migrate() to fail.